# XAMPP - PHP not parsing on virtualhost

Tags: php, parsing, xampp, virtualhost

I've set up a virtual host for my local machine.

This is what I have in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost local.dev
127.0.1.1   tomica-ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

This is configuration for that virtual host in my `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev"
    ServerName local.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

In my `/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/index.html` I have this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>HTML</p>
    <?php echo 'PHP' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open `http://local.dev` in my browser, I only see:

```
HTML
```

However, if I open the document source, I can see:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>HTML</p>
    <?php echo 'PHP' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And if I inspect the page's DOM, there's:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>HTML</p>
    <!--<?php echo 'PHP' ?>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Also, if I rename `/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/index.html` to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev/index.php` everything seems to be alright.

Why is my PHP code not parsing in the .html document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `mod_php` does not tell Apache to let it handle documents with the `.html` extension.  If you change the handler type using the [`AddHandler` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler):

```
AddHandler php-script .html
```

then Apache will know that you want to let PHP process the contents of files with a `html` extension.

The reason this is not enabled by default is because running a document through the PHP interpreter costs (in CPU, in memory usage, in end-user time).  There is no point in wasting time - so in mod_php's default setup HTML files (which normally are static affairs) are not passed through the PHP interpreter.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you @Sean. Although I had to modify it a little bit. So in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev` I created a `.htaccess` file and put this in: `AddHandler php5-script .html`

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ - that will work too - I was thinking that it could be added to your `VirtualHost` section in your `.conf` file - but .htaccess will work too :-)

Comment: I got it, it's just that I feel I'm still too new in server setting that I'm trying to do as much as possible on a per-project basis :) Your help is much appreciated.