# Dynamically-generated PHP script doesn't parse; straight-code does

Tags: php, apache

This file (`test.php`) runs the PHP info blurb as expected:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php  
   phpinfo();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But this code, also when saved as `test.php`, generates a blank screen:

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><?php phpinfo(); ?></body></html>";
?>
```

The source code here, when reviewed from the browser, shows:

```
 <html><body><?php phpinfo(); ?></body></html>
```

...so almost certainly there is something screwy about how I've set up the server to parse things..

I am running a localhost of PHP version 5.6.28 and Apache 2.4 on Windows 10. Other than the newbie setup instructions [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/), I haven't changed many of the defaults.  I do have:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

...already in the `httpd.conf` file.

`test.php` definitely has a .php extension already, but I did see [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541345/xampp-php-not-parsing-on-virtualhost), so I added this line:

```
AddHandler php-script .html
```

...to the `httpd.conf` file.  I also added:

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
AddType text.html .php
```

that were suggested here: [Apache is downloading php files instead of displaying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them)

Am I missing something obvious?

**Update:** after monkeying by adding the above lines to the `httpd.conf` file, `test.php` actually generates a few unescaped characters?

"; ?>

rather than a totally blank screen, or the expected phpinfo information.

Comment: You are echoing out PHP code to output, that output will not be parsed by the PHP engine.

Comment: So maybe `echo` isn't what I want -- how can I create code -- in a string, say -- that will be executed?  For example, creating forms from code:  echo '<form id="option-listing-form" method="post" action=" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[&#39;PHP_SELF&#39;]); ?> "> ';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the comment you posted above, you're looking to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) output. Using your example, you could use:

```
echo '<form id="option-listing-form" method="post" action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '"> ';
```

Hope this helps :)